# Behat, Symfony 2 and FOS User: how to create a login test

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, behat

I'm new with Behat and I want to create a feature to validate the login form. I'm using FOS User bundle.

The easiest way to go is do something like:

```
When I am on "/login"
And I fill in "username" with "admin"
And I fill in "password" with "1234"
And I press "_submit"
Then I should be on "/dashboard"
```

expecting that the user "admin" exists in the database with the 1234 password. But I'm pretty sure there must be a way to mock the database or create a fake user for FOS. I've been googling but couldn't find anything specific.

Ideally I think it should be something like

```
Given there's a user "admin" with password "1234"
[rest of the test]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could define a specific step to log in, and reuse it in your different tests. You don't even need the password, authentification is simulated through tokens.

For example :

```
/**
 * @Given /^I am authenticated as "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iAmAuthenticatedAs($username)
{
    $driver = $this->getSession()->getDriver();
    if (!$driver instanceof BrowserKitDriver) {
        throw new UnsupportedDriverActionException('This step is only supported by the BrowserKitDriver');
    }

    $client = $driver->getClient();
    $client->getCookieJar()->set(new Cookie(session_name(), true));

    $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');

    $user = $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByUsername($username);
    $providerKey = $this->kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
    $session->set('_security_'.$providerKey, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

And then call this new step with :

```
Scenario: Displaying the blog overview
Given I am authenticated as "bar"
  And I am on "/admin/"
 Then I should see "Admin dashboard"
```

**Useful content :**

- [Source for this code](http://www.robinvdvleuten.nl/blog/handle-authenticated-users-in-behat-mink/)
- [Behat documentation about custom steps](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/2.definitions.html)

Comment: Yes, but I want to test the specific login page, not a page which requires to be logged in. I want to test that when I  go to /login and I provide good credentials I'll be logged in

Comment: Then you should read the first part of [this link](http://www.robinvdvleuten.nl/blog/handle-authenticated-users-in-behat-mink/). It gives a code example to achieve authentication through a login form submission.

Comment: but the problem with that link is that it doesn't explain how to create the step of creating the users. I already got into it :)

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you could create a user on the fly with `$this->get('fos_user.util.user_manipulator')->create($username, $password, $email, 1, 0);`, try to connect with it using the login form, and delete it afterwards (in three different custom steps).

Comment: That would work, I only need now to delete it afterwards

Comment: You can use `$this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->deleteUser($user);` where `user` is the UserInterface your got when you created your temporary user.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the FOSUserBundle login form you could write your feature like this

```
Feature: Admin authentication
  In order to gain access to my admin management area
  As an admin
  I need to be able to login

  Scenario: Logging in
    Given there is an admin user "admin" with password "1234"
    And I am on "/login"
    When I fill in "Username" with "admin"
    And I fill in "Password" with "1234"
    And I press "Log in"
    Then I should see "Connected" //or anything that proves you're connected
```

Then you can create the step validation in your FeatureContext.php like this :

```
/**
 * @Given there is an admin user :username with password :password
 */
public function thereIsAnAdminUserWithPassword($username, $password)
{   // Create an Admin User
    $user = new \AppBundle\Entity\User();// inherits form FOSUserBundle\Entity\User()
    $user->setUsername($username);
    $user->setPlainPassword($password);
    $user->setEmail("example@mail.com");// required by FOSUserBundle
    $user->setEnabled(true); // add it manually otherwise you'll get "Account is disabled" error
    $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN'));

    // Then you must store it in your database
}
```

The problem is that FeatureContext.php cannot access the container and the entity manager and cannot store you user in the database if you don't declare it explicitly. The easiest way is to use the behat/symfony2-extension, then only you'll be able to use the entity manager and store an admin user. If you're using Composer then you can :

```
composer require --dev behat/symfony2-extension
```

Then you must activate the extension in your behat.yml like this :

```
default:
# ...
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
```

And only then you can make your FeatureContext.php aware of the container so that it can access the entity manager. Add it right inside your FeatureContext class like this :

```
class FeatureContext extends RawMinkContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
    {
        use \Behat\Symfony2Extension\Context\KernelDictionary;
    ...
    }
```

Now you can call the entity manager and store your admin user :

```
/**
 * @Given there is an admin user :username with password :password
 */
public function thereIsAnAdminUserWithPassword($username, $password)
{   // Create an Admin User
    $user = new \AppBundle\Entity\User();
    $user->setUsername($username);
    $user->setPlainPassword($password);
    $user->setEmail("example@mail.com");
    $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
    $user->setEnabled(true); 

    // Store it in the database
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Now you can use your test ! Don't forget to clean the database before you launch the test otherwise on your second try you'll get a nice error saying that this user already exists ! The best is to add a clearData() function that launches before every scenario like this one :

```
/**
 * @BeforeScenario
 */
public function clearData()
{
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM AppBundle:User')->execute();
}
```

Good luck !